# Literature reviews on nerve conduction velocity?

Tags: neuroscience, neurophysiology, electrophysiology

The [Wikipedia article for nerve conduction velocity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nerve_conduction_velocity) is frustrating because it lacks citations. **What is a good survey or overview of the research on nerve conduction velocity?**

I'm particularly interested in understanding the conduction velocity of neurons in a human brain. I know very little neuroscience, but it seems to me like the Wikipedia article primarily covers conduction velocities of neurons in other parts of the human nervous system.

Comment: https://psychology.stackexchange.com/questions/16993/delay-time-of-transmitting-the-information-from-one-neuron-to-another-in-brain/ https://psychology.stackexchange.com/questions/12403/how-long-does-it-take-for-electrical-impulses-from-neurons-to-travel-in-the-huma/ https://psychology.stackexchange.com/questions/28947/how-can-you-set-the-axonal-length-in-a-recurrent-neural-network/